# Active load with mosfet and op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, batteries, mosfet

Below is the circuit I used to implement an active load which use an op-amp to adjust the mosfets' resistance based on DAC voltage at the op-amp input.

VIN_NANO is about 10VDC.

Mosfet is IXYS IXFH28N60P3, Vds: 600V, On-resistance: 260mOhm @ 14A,10V Vgs, power dissipation: 695 Watt.

The scheme works well with Battery String voltage of 12VDC. When I increase it to 125 VDC, the mosfets die almost instantaneously. What would be the reason behind this?

[image]

Test load current looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Your mosfet's [Vgs is 30-40v](http://ixapps.ixys.com/Datasheet/DS100322A(IXFQ-FH28N60P3).pdf), which is less than 125v

Comment: Not sure how you're getting 2A peak out of it even... The maximum current through R20 is:

I = Vdac * R20/(R20+R12)

(Golden op-amp rule, V+ terminal = V- terminal, then apply a voltage divider equation to R20)

10 * 1/(1001) ~ 10mA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devices you have do not have a suitable DC SOA. The device is rated only for pulse operation at high powers. Going beyond 1 ms on time puts you in a very dark place.

You need to use something like an [IXTH30N60L2](http://ixapps.ixys.com/DataSheet/DS100101(IXTH-TQ-TT30N60L2).pdf) ...these devices are rated for large linear load dissipation.

Read [this](http://www.ixyspower.com/images/literature/250V-600V_Linear_L2_TM.pdf) on the L2 range from IXYS.

For the devices you chose, SOA is this: 
[image]

You actually need something like this:
[image]

....for your application you could use just two devices with plenty of margin or select a larger one and use just a single device.

Comment: Should I use RMS current or Peak current to select the appropriate Mosfet?

Comment: You can only use RMS if you are providing a continuous waveform load. In the case of a load provider application I'd design for a DC load (no waveform).